# How to make the select statement show only 'PM' and not 'AM' when selecting hour from a time stamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to write a select statement that will only show PM but no AM.
I still want to show the AM results.. but with out the 'AM' after the hour part..

> For example..  instead of showing 8 AM i only want 8 but if its 7 PM,
>   I want to show it as 7 PM.

how can I achieve this?

I tried this, but this will give me both AM and PM.. But I only want PM to show.

```
select to_char(po.pick_date,'HH12 PM') as Hour from tableA where x = y;
```

Is this possible to do in the select statement?  Or do I need some other way to weed out the AM's from the result set?

Comment: MySQL does not have a `to_char()` function.  Hence, your question does not make sense.  I removed the MySQL tag, because you claim that the code actually works.

Comment: Oracle.. sorry. not mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `replace()`:

```
select replace(to_char(po.pick_date, 'HH12 PM'), ' AM', '') as Hour
from tableA
where x = y;
```

Based on the use of `to_char()`, I speculate that your database is either Oracle or Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

To answer it generally, since your RDBMS provider is in question:

Assuming your provider has date formatting functions you should be able to something like:

CASE WHEN *time part in am* THEN *format without am/pm suffix* ELSE *format with am/pm suffix* END

or something like

concatenate *format without am/pm suffix* with CASE WHEN *time part in pm* THEN "PM" ELSE "" END